# Cefsharp and video tag WebRTC

Tags: wpf, webrtc, cefsharp, html5-video

I'm trying to write a wpf with webrtc support. The access to the camera works but the display of the `<video>` from the page doesn't. Can anyone help?

Comment: How are you trying to attach it to the tag? What code are you willing to share so that we can help?

Comment: Does e.g. https://simpl.info/webrtc/ represent what you want to do? I got the getUserMedia() example from there working

Comment: I just want to display video from a html5 page with the <video> in it

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like this:

```
var cefSettings = new CefSettings();
cefSettings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("enable-media-stream", "enable-media-stream");
Cef.Initialize(cefSettings);
```

This has the same effect as passing the command line argument

Answer (score 2):

I assume you want to display video from your camera via WebRTC so I think it requires a call to `.getUserMedia()` to get hold of your camera. For that to work you must use CefSharp based on Chromium 30 or later. So either:

- Use the latest CefSharp.Wpf NuGet. Right now you need latest `-Pre` release
- or build from source with the current `master` branch.

I just did a quick test again using [CefSharp.MinimalExample](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample) so here are the steps:

1. Make sure your MinimalExample uses Chromium 31 or higher - see [this PR](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample/pull/2) - unless it already got merged by the time you are reading this.
2. In `MainView.xaml` modify the `<cefSharp:WebView Address= />` attribute to "https://simpl.info/getusermedia/sources/index.html"
3. Build and when running add the `--enable-media-stream` command line flag.

That's it! With your camera connected and a bit of luck you should see your own face - or whatever the camera points to - on the screen.

**Bonus info:** Hopefully soon PR #365 can get a bit of extra love to allow for passing flags too and get merged into CefSharp. With that you can set the flag in code instead of having to pass it in as a command line parameter.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. My problem is to display the video file/output from the given url. Like watching videos on youtube.

Comment: Ah, so nothing to do with the camera - but you have a video file or is  it a stream at what kind of URL and in what format (i.e. you must be sure it's a format/codec supported by Chromium? - which doesn't have all the one's that e.g. Chrome has due to licensing)

Comment: To re-iterate a bit on what @bwtrent said above. Share some more details/code on "what have you tried" what is your setup - CefSharp version/binary or source install video formats etc. (Which DLLs mentioned in the CefSharp wiki FAQ etc do you have) and it's easier to help.

Comment: Just to add to the Bonus Info point: 
You can add command lines now using CefSettings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add

Comment: added these args, still not working. the args are name value pairs. What actually are the name value pair values?

settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("--enable-media-stream", "--enable-media-stream");

settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("--enable-usermedia-screen-capturing", "--enable-usermedia-screen-capturing");

settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("enable-usermedia-screen-capturing", "enable-usermedia-screen-capturing");

settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("enable-media-stream", "enable-media-stream");

Comment: You probably need to get rid of the --'s and the values so try it like settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("enable-media-stream", "");

Comment: @jornh I cant find this method in CefCommandLineArgs in 33.02 version.Doyou have any idea how it's done now?

Comment: AFAIK it should still be the same. Does the comments in https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/v33.1.0-pre01/CefSharp.Example/CefExample.cs#L17 give some (enough) context?

Answer (score 0):

The correct code is this
 `Dim settings As New CefSettings settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("--enable-media-stream", "1") CefSharp.Cef.Initialize(settings) settings.CachePath = "cache"`