# CefSharp WebCam not rendering

Tags: wpf, video, cefsharp

I created a CefSharp WPF application. The webview directed to a page which access the webcam. I could see the plugin started working perfectly (my system webcam switched on). But the video not showing up.

Any suggestions are really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23834937/210723) for a WebRTC based solution (or give more details to what you try to do like what JavaScript API your page use, what CefSharp version you use, code sample etc.)